# Is there any active community for apache camel like slack or any

Tags: apache-camel, slack, spring-camel

While developing spring boot application with apache camel I facing lot of issues, could anyone please give active **slack or any community links**, so that I'll join in and take community help.

Answer (score 1):

See [here on the Camel website](https://camel.apache.org/community/support/)

There is a [mailing list](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-Users-f465428.html) and a [Zulip chat room](https://camel.zulipchat.com).

The formerly on the Camel website mentioned [Gitter community](https://gitter.im/apache/apache-camel) seems to be deprecated.